# How to generate correctly SOAP WSDL requests from array with multiple items with same name in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I need to generate following XML Soap request in PHP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <ns1:SomeRequest enddate="01-01-2018 00:00:00" authCode="exampleexample"> 
            <ns1:status>STATUS1</ns1:status> 
            <ns1:status>STATUS2</ns1:status> 
        </ns1:SomeRequest> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying like that:

```
$this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdlUrl, [
    'trace' => true,
    'exception' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
]);

$parameters = [
    'authCode' => 'exampleexample',
    'enddate' => '01-01-2018 00:00:00',
    'status' => ['STATUS1', 'STATUS2']
];

$response = $this->client->SomeSimpleMethod($parameters);
```

And receive **Array to string conversion** error.
When I'm trying pass status as string, like that:

```
$parameters = [
    'authCode' => 'exampleexample',
    'enddate' => '01-01-2018 00:00:00',
    'status' => 'STATUS1'
];
```

Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a WSDL to PHP generator as you won't wonder how to correctly construct the request. As it is not always straightforward to do so, using the generated classes to construct the request and to send it, you will easily send the request and handle the response using the OOP approach.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which is best suited to generate a PHP SDK from any SOAP WSDL.